# Connecting to Paradox database through Windows ODBCCONF command line

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, odbc, paradox

I use Eclipse to manipulate Paradox databases with a HXTT Paradox Driver. But now i would like to create data sources through Windows ODBC and use ODBC-JDBC bridge for connection through command line or .BAT files.

[image: Paradox database connection through Windows ODBC via GUI]

I've tried the following:

```
Driver={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 5.X;
DefaultDir=c:C:\Path;Dbq=C:\Path;CollatingSequence=ASCII;
```

But even though i get no errors, nothing happens (no DSN is created in Windows). So i would like to know the correct syntax to connect with a Paradox database (which is just a folder) via a .BAT file using **Windows ODBCCONF**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
odbcconf configdsn "Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )" "DSN=WKS|DBQ=c:\receptor"
```

For configdsn, the parameter receives the **driver name**. The other two parameters set the **DSN name and database folder**, respectively.

This turned out to be pretty simple. Works exactly as i want it to, but now i need to figure out how to remove the DSN after i am done working with it.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Please can you provide a simple query command that you execute after connecting to Paradox?

Comment: I don't have any examples (i was using this in company where i worked 3 years ago) :(. Sorry